# how can i set view like alert and hide automatically in iOS

Tags: ios, alert

In my application i want to set black view like alert and it is hide automatically with the fade in and fade out animation .
[image]

Like this view. Any control available for this requirement.I am newly in iOS development.Thank you In advanced.

Comment: SubClass UiView and add it to your view

Comment: hi @Apple insider you can simply add view and label on windows and show using static method call.

Comment: i am new in this please can u provide some code or link reference ? Thanks your comment .

Comment: This is called a toast message. There  are lots of third-party controls which can do this for you. look at https://cocoapods.org/?q=toast or https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi These are static methods put in your static class.

```
    +(void)ShowSimpleBlackAlert:(NSString *)str
    {

        CGSize sizeLine = [StaticClass getFrameFromString:str :[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-60 :[UIFont fontWithName:font_NAME_OpenSans size:15]]; // user your custom font

        UIView * viewAlert =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-50)/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-40,sizeLine.height+50)];
        viewAlert.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
        viewAlert.alpha=0.0;
        viewAlert.layer.cornerRadius=5.0;
        viewAlert.tag=200;

        UILabel *_titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,(viewAlert.frame.size.height-sizeLine.height)/2,viewAlert.frame.size.width-20,sizeLine.height)];
        _titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        _titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        _titleLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:font_NAME_OpenSans size:15.0]; // user your custom font
        _titleLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _titleLabel.text=str;

        [viewAlert addSubview:_titleLabel];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:viewAlert];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             viewAlert.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideSimpleBlackAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

and Other hide method...

```
+(void)hideSimpleBlackAlert
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                     [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow viewWithTag:200] removeFromSuperview];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

and user like this

```
[yourStaticClass ShowAlert:@"put here your message "];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use third party libraries for your requirement.

1) [AFMInfoBanner](https://github.com/ask-fm/AFMInfoBanner). It can be used to unobtrusively notify users about successful or erroneous events which do not require any specific action or UI locking.

2) [ALAlertBanner](https://github.com/alobi/ALAlertBanner). It is a drop-in component for iOS (both iPhone and iPad) that allows you to display beautiful alert banners in a customizable and configurable way.

Answer (score 0):

Andriod like toast in ios .you can modify it as per requirement

https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios